# My build trigger is not recognizing the glob pattern

Tags: google-cloud-platform, glob, google-cloud-build

I have two folders in my main directory, cloud_functions and cloudbuild:

```
├── cloud_functions
│   ├── batch_predict
│   │   ├── config.py
│       ├── main.py
│       ├── requirements.txt
│       └── utils.py
├── cloudbuild
│   ├── batch_predict_cloud_function
│   │   ├── config.yaml
│   │   ├── create_triggers.sh
```

In the Cloud build trigger I specified the glob patterns as:

- cloud_functions/batch_predict/**
- cloudbuild/batch_predict_cloud_function/**

This is accomplished with the following flag in the gcloud command that creates the trigger:

```
--included-files="cloud_functions/batch_predict/**, cloudbuild/batch_predict_cloud_function/**" \
```

I validated the globs are registered in the UI but changes in the cloudbuild folder don't trigger the build, any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: I am not sure if it's supported multiple glob pattern in a trigger. What if you create two triggers one for each glob pattern cloud_functions/batch_predict/** and cloudbuild/batch_predict_cloud_function/** ?

Comment: In the docs it says it supports multiple globs.

Comment: How did you defined both globs in the trigger?

Comment: Can you show either gcloud command or terraform files which define/create the cloud build trigger, please?

Comment: @al-dann see edit

Comment: the next guess - are both those changes happen on push in the correct (stated in the cloud build trigger) git branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify multiple glob patterns in the `gcloud` command you have to pass multiple arguments to the `--included-files` option using the following syntax:

```
--included-files "cloud_functions/batch_predict/**","cloudbuild/batch_predict_cloud_function/**"
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I get an error separating the strings.

Comment: I just edited the answer, there was an extra space after the `,`